# Is there any sound enhancer software for Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, user-experience

One of my biggest attachments to Windows is [DFX Audio Enhancer](http://www.fxsound.com/) because it enhances audio from all applications before reaching my speakers (Restore quality, ambiance/surround simulation, etc.). Is there any similar software/configuration for Linux?

[SRS HD Audio Lab](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=srs+hd+audio+lab) (Formerly SRS Audio Sandbox) is kind of the same thing (In case you don't know DFX).

Any guidance would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.
[Sorry for my bad english]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PulseAudio then it's possible to use the [`module-pipe-*` modules](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules#module-pipe-sink) to feed the audio data through a [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) executable that has been passed appropriate parameters. Note that this will add a small amount of latency to the audio though, with the specific amount dependent on the SoX parameters.

Comment: can you please give us sample of how to use sox for some media player output or music coming from browser?